# How can I make my Line Graph appear?

Tags: vb.net, graph, charts

I am trying to programatically get my `Chart` object to appear. I have been able to get the Chart to appear using the `Design` file, but for what I am doing, i need to understand how the `Chart Control` works programatically.

This is my code:

```
    Dim wavesGraph As New Chart()

    Dim chartarea As New ChartArea

    Dim vn1Series As New Series("VN1", SeriesChartType.Line)
    Dim vn2Series As New Series("VN2", SeriesChartType.Line)
    Dim vn3Series As New Series("VN3", SeriesChartType.Line)
    Dim vdi1Series As New Series("VDI1", SeriesChartType.Line)
    Dim vdi2Series As New Series("VDI2", SeriesChartType.Line)
    Dim vdi3Series As New Series("VDI3", SeriesChartType.Line)


    wavesGraph.ChartAreas.Add(chartarea)

    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vn1Series)
    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vn2Series)
    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vn3Series)
    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vdi1Series)
    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vdi2Series)
    wavesGraph.Series.Add(vdi3Series)

    Console.WriteLine("Here1")
    wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).Visible = True


    wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True
    wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Network Voltage"
    If (WavesIsI) Then

        wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Title = "Network Current"
    Else
        wavesGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Title = "Differential Volts"
    End If
    wavesGraph.Series("VDI1").YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    wavesGraph.Series("VDI2").YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    wavesGraph.Series("VDI3").YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary


    Dim rand As New Random
    Console.WriteLine("Here2")

    For i As Integer = 0 To 166

        wavesGraph.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
        'wavesGraph.Series(1).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
        'wavesGraph.Series(2).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
        wavesGraph.Series(3).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
        'wavesGraph.Series(4).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
        'wavesGraph.Series(5).Points.AddXY(i, rand.Next(-255, 255))
    Next
    wavesGraph.Enabled = True
    wavesGraph.Visible = True
    Console.WriteLine("Here3")
```

This is the resulting Line Graph that I get:
[image]

Comment: I copied your code 1:1 and just added a `Me.Controls.Add(wavesGraph)` at the end to add the graph to the form (you do that somewhere apparently since you can see the chart control) and it works fine. What other code are you using?

Comment: Wow, thank you you solved my problem. What was happening was an old `Chart` control that I added via the `Design` file was still appearing when I launched the application. Deleting that `Chart`, and adding the line `Me.Controls.Add(wavesGraph)` solved my problem. If you would put this as an answer I will accept it for you.

Comment: Good to hear. I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code 1:1 and just added `Me.Controls.Add(wavesGraph)` at the end to add the graph to the form.

You did not add the control to the form in any way so the newly created graph never shows up.